# Set New page when running total limit exceeds 10000 in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Need to Set new page, when running total limit exceeds 10000 in Crystal Reports. In a page the running total amount should not exceed 10000, if it goes greater than 10000, the next record should print on the next page. Any ideas?

ACUBE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a new page every time your running total hit 10000 do this:

create a 1st formula with a numbervar initialized in 0 in your PH, then create a 2nd formula where you simulate what your running total does. Then a 3rd formula that will show up the returned value per group of the 2nd formula placed on where your running total is. Then put that 3rd formula > 10000 as a condition for new page after. So will be like this:

```
 formula1 -> numbervar test := 0 placed in your PH
 formula2 -> numbervar test := test + {your running total based field(amount field)} placed suppressed where the amount field is.
 formula3 -> numbervar test
 new page after condition -> formula3 > 10000
```

in that way your running total get reset every 10000 total amount